# Does the standard have any normative wording for a function with no return type?

Tags: c, function, language-lawyer, return-type

Although many compilers are tolerant of a function with no return type, the standard as of N1570 doesn't seem to have a normative wording for it. Why is that possible?

Comment: To declare a function without result, you use the pseudo-type `void` as result type. But what do you mean with wording?

Comment: @Olaf It is possible to declare a function without a return type. However, the standard does not say a word about it, I guess.

Comment: Implicit int return types are no longer part of the standard. Read C89 if you want to see the old spec. Compilers still tend to support the implicit return type for backward compatibility.

Comment: A function cannot not have a return type.

Comment: @user2357112 That's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @KerrekSB That's the point of my question. However, many compilers still support it apparently.

Comment: The current and **only** valid C standard is [C11](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html).

Comment: @Il-seobBae: You misunderstand. Every function has a return type. Perhaps you don't *spell out* a return type consciously (though as said above that's not allowed in Standard C), but the function still ends up having a return type. (It's probably `int`.)

Comment: @KerrekSB I got your point.

Comment: The function must have a return type. In C11 there is _Noreturn to say that this function will no return at all, but it still will have a return type.

Comment: void fun(args...){ function statements;.... }

Comment: Note that in C++, we do have such functions, namely constructors and destructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original C standard (C89, C90), section 6.7.1 covered function definitions.  In the C99 and C11 standards, section 6.9.1 covers function definitions.  There's a small but crucial difference between the two.

### ISO/IEC 9899:1990

> #### §6.7.1 Function definitions
>
> **Syntax**
>
> *function definition:*
>             *declaration-specifiers<sub>opt</sub>   declarator   declaration-list<sub>opt</sub>   compound-statement*

### ISO/IEC 9899:1999 and ISO/IEC 9899:2011

> #### §6.9.1 Function definitions
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ¶1  *function definition:*
>             *declaration-specifiers   declarator   declaration-list<sub>opt</sub>   compound-statement*

The subscript *<sub>opt</sub>* is missing from *declaration-specifiers* in the later versions of the standard.

That's all that's present in the 'Function definitions' section of any of the standards that controls the return type.

The next two paragraphs are common between all three versions of the standard (though there's a footnote with different numbers that I've omitted).

> ¶2 The identifier declared in a function definition (which is the name of the function) shall have a function type, as specified in the declarator portion of the function definition.
>
> ¶3 The return type of a function shall be `void` or a complete object type other than array type.

The *declaration-specifiers* could omit a type (so it could state `static` or `extern` without a type).  In C90, this was legitimate; in C99 and C11, this is not allowed.  The relevant sections for this are §6.5.2 in C90 and §6.7.2 in C99 and C11, for type specifiers.

### ISO/IEC 9899:1990

> #### Type specifiers
>
> **Constraints**
>   Each list of type specifiers shall be one of the following sets (delimited by commas, when
>   there is more than one set on a line); the type specifiers may occur in any order, possibly
>   intermixed with the other declaration specifiers.

### ISO/IEC 9899:1999 and ISO/IEC 9899:2011

> #### 6.7.2 Type specifiers
>
> **Constraints**
>   At least one type specifier shall be given in the declaration specifiers in each declaration,
>   and in the specifier-qualifier list in each struct declaration and type name. Each list of
>   type specifiers shall be one of the following sets (delimited by commas, when there is
>   more than one set on a line); the type specifiers may occur in any order, possibly
>   intermixed with the other declaration specifiers.

The first sentence in the C99/C11 text rules out the possibility of a declaration specifier that does not include a type, whereas C90 is silent on the point so a declaration specifier may omit the type.

### Enforcement

Until recently (GCC 5), the GNU C Compiler used the C90 standard as its default mode of operation, so it was lax about allowing function definitions without an explicit return type, because the C90 standard was lax about it.  Given the state of C code in 1989 or 1990, this laxness was necessary as a lot of existing code at the time did not include a return type.  Had the C90 standard been strict about this, it would have failed.  As it was, it succeeded extremely well.

Starting with GCC 5.1, the GNU C Compiler defaults to the C11 standard as its default mode of operation, so it generates warnings about functions defined without a return type.  You can convert those warnings into errors if you wish.  Let's restate that: you **should** convert those warnings into errors, and then fix the code so that the warnings are no longer generated.

Consider the sloppy (by modern standards) code stored in a file `old-style.c`:

```
function(int x)
{
    return 2 * x * x + 3 * x - 7;
}
```

Compiling on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.4 using GCC 6.3.0, I get:

```
$ gcc -c old-style.c
old-style.c:1:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 function(int x)
 ^~~~~~~~
$ gcc -std=c11 -c old-style.c
old-style.c:1:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 function(int x)
 ^~~~~~~~
$ gcc -std=c99 -c old-style.c
old-style.c:1:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 function(int x)
 ^~~~~~~~
$ gcc -std=c90 -c old-style.c
$
```

Thus, only with the C90 standard specified do I get a 'clean' (warning-free) compilation under default options.

Adding `-Werror` or `-Werror=implict-int` converts these warnings into errors:

```
$ gcc -Werror -std=c11 -c old-style.c
old-style.c:1:1: error: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Werror=implicit-int]
 function(int x)
 ^~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$ gcc -Werror=implicit-int -std=c11 -c old-style.c
old-style.c:1:1: error: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Werror=implicit-int]
 function(int x)
 ^~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
$
```

The difference is that the plain `-Werror` makes *all* warnings into errors, but `-Werror=implicit-int` makes on that warning into an error (other warnings remain as warnings).

My own coding standard requires that a non-static function be declared with a full prototype before it is defined or used.  Static functions may be defined without a prior prototype before they are used.  Further, any non-static function declarations should be in a header; the only reason a function is not static is because it will be used by another source file, and the header is necessary to allow the compiler to check consistency between the places where the function is defined and where it is used.
Thus, my default compilation options are:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes \
>     -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -std=c11 -c old-style.c
old-style.c:1:1: error: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Werror=implicit-int]
 function(int x)
 ^~~~~~~~
old-style.c:1:1: error: no previous prototype for ‘function’ [-Werror=missing-prototypes]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

Some versions of GCC don't support both the `-Wold-style-xxx` options, and Clang doesn't like the `-Wold-style-declaration` option either, so I omit that quite often.

Fixing the in `new-style.c` is fairly easy:

```
extern int function(int x);     /* Should be in a header */

int function(int x)
{
    return 2 * x * x + 3 * x - 7;
}
```

And that compiles under the stringent compilation options with nary a squeak:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes \
>     -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -std=c11 -c new-style.c
$
```

The rules for other compilers vary similarly to GCC — different versions may do different things, and complain by default about different issues, and require different options to make them produce the diagnostics you need.  It is always helpful to use more than one compiler, preferably on more than one platform, to check how well code works.